# Как исправить алгоритм цикла чтобы отображался искомый параметр?

Tags: алгоритм, циклы, matlab

Необходимо с помощью Matlab аппроксимировать ряд:

```
y(n)=(1/0!) + (1/1!)+..+(1/n!)
```

И необходимо найти n,для которого y будет равен exp(1).
Я написал следующий код для решения этой задачи:

```
for n=1:100
    while y>exp(1)
        y=(1/(factorial(n-1)))
        y=y+(1/(factorial(n)))
        disp(n)
    end
end
```

Но `n` не отражается и перепробовав варианты данного кода не получается найти `n`. Подскажите как решить задачу?

Comment: `while y>exp(1)` мне кажется вы что-то со знаком не то написали. Частичная сумма ряда меньше предела всегда. И ещё `y= ... y=y+` вы точно не ошиблись? Мне кажется присваивание тут лишнее. Я никогда в матлабе не писал но я бы сделал `while ( exp(1) - y > 1e-10) y = y + (1/(factorial(n))`. Кстати ответ вопрос _когда_ - никогда!

Comment: @pavel Теоретически никогда, но поскольку работа идёт с ограниченной точностью (64 бита), то довольно скоро: при n=17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не нужно цикла for. Есть одно условие: y < exp(1), по нему работает цикл while. Внутри цикла прибавляем 1/factorial(n) и увеличиваем значение n.

```
n = 0;
y = 0;
while y < exp(1)
  y = y + 1/factorial(n);
  n = n + 1;
end
disp(n - 1)
```

Ответ: 17. (В конце отнимается единица, потому что она была добавлена в последнем проходе цикла.)

Нужно иметь в виду, что частичная сумма этого ряда на самом деле никогда не будет равна числу e. Равенство достигается только из-за округления вызванного конечной точностью представления чисел в Matlab.